# jQuery UI select menu - How to prevent standard select rendering at page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm using [jQuery UI Selectmenu](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/) to style my selects, but I have a little glitch with the initial transition after page loads, when the standard select control is replaced by the jquery UI version.
Is there a good technique to make this ugly transition not visible at all?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can wrap your select with some invisible element and show it only after page is loaded. 
Also appearing will be more nice if you will use something like this:

```
$("selectWrapper").show(1000);
```